# Webpack v4 — how to access 'mode' option value

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

Webpack v4 has introduced two sets of defaults: `production` and `development`. My question is: Is there a way to refer to those inside a configuration file? I know I can still pass environment variables as:

```
--env.NODE_ENV=development
```

by doing this I have two independent environment variables and this doesn't feel right. Another option would be obviously to refer to a different config file and this doesn't look like an optimal solution for simple configurations as well.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found a better way in [a webpack github issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6460).
Since webpack 2 you can export a function in `webpack.config.js`, the parsed `argv` will be passed to that function.

For webpack 4 you can write the config like:

```
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = (env, argv) => {
    console.log(argv.mode);
    return { /* your config object */ };
};

// $webpack-cli --mode development
// development
```

---

Original Answer:

You can use some libs like `minimist` to parse the arguments passed by the cli:

```
// webpack.config.js
const args = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2));
console.log(args.mode);

// $webpack-cli --mode development
// development
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about `process.argv` property. Are there any downsides to this method? It has never occurred to me before. Is it due to relative inconvenience of parsing it?

Comment: @oniondomes It's usually used in command-line tools to parse options, for example [webpack-cli](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli/blob/master/bin/webpack.js#L217). It's not so common in config files since it's not so declarative, but I think it's very suitable for your case.

Comment: Didn't notice your edit. I've been expecting to find something like this when I was asking the question. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I've just built this simple NPM package for importing current Webpack 4 mode: https://github.com/mckomo/webpack-mode. Here is how you can use it:

```
// webpack.config.js
const { isProduction } = require('webpack-mode');

console.log(isProduction); // => true

// ... rest of the config
```

It works very simply, just reads process arguments to determine the value of `mode` argument. By default `webpack-mode.isProduction` will return `true` (original behaviour of the Webpack 4).

Comment: Please do read the [rules on self-promotion](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).

Comment: @EJoshuaS Correct me if I'm wrong, but it doesn't seem like he's breaking any of those rules. He discloses that he wrote it, and shows how to use it to answer the question.

Comment: I think that @chrisz put it well. I just can add that I build this package especially to address problem asked in the question. I added link to the my repository, as README is more complete than my answer and I really did not want to just copy/past it here. DRY right?